# Need help understanding python threading flavors

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm into threads now and exploring thread and threading libraries. When I started with them, I wrote 2 basic programs. The following are the 2 programs with their corresponding outputs:

### threading_1.py :

```
import threading

def main():
    t1=threading.Thread(target=prints,args=(3,))
    t2=threading.Thread(target=prints,args=(5,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

def prints(i):
    while(i>0):
        print "i="+str(i)+"\n"
        i=i-1

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

### output :

```
i=3

i=2
i=5


i=4
i=1


i=3

i=2

i=1
```

### thread_1.py

```
import thread
import threading

def main():
    t1=thread.start_new_thread(prints,(3,))
    t2=thread.start_new_thread(prints,(5,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

def prints(i):
    while(i>0):
        print "i="+str(i)+"\n"
        i=i-1

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

### output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
i=3
  File "thread_1.py", line 19, in <module>

    i=2

i=1
main()

i=5

i=4

i=3

i=2

i=1

  File "thread_1.py", line 8, in main
    t1.start()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'start'
```

My desired output is as in threading_1.py where interleaved prints makes it a convincing example of thread executions. My understanding is that *"threading"* is a *higher-class library* compared to *"thread"*. And the *AttributeError* I get in thread_1.py is because I am operating on a thread started from thread library and not threading.

So, now my question is - how do I achieve an output similar to the output of threading_1.py using thread_1.py. Can the program be modified or tuned to produce the same result?

Comment: You shouldn't really use the `thread` library at all. (It's even been renamed to `_thread` in Python 3 to make that clearer.) Why do you want to do this?

Comment: But the answer is, just leave out the `.start` and the `.join` calls entirely. `start_new_thread` already starts the thread, and when it finishes it exits silently. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread).

Comment: I've tried that too...then it just prints "i=5" and exits. Is _thread_ actually a defunct library replaced by _threading_? In what cases, do we use _thread_ then? Could you please explain a bit more on that? I'm fine with _threading_ library.

Comment: `thread` is a low-level library that's used to abstract away platform details and provide the essential bits and pieces that the `threading` library needs; it's really there for the convenience of those who develop Python, not for those who use it. So as a user, you'd hardly ever care about the `thread` library: just use `threading`.

Comment: " it just prints "i=5" and exits" <- that's because there's nothing preventing the main thread from exiting immediately. If you do a `time.sleep` (or maybe make a `raw_input` call) in the main thread you'll see the full output from your background threads.

Comment: So, _thread_ manages most of the things implicitly compared to _threading_ which needs to be done explicitly. Say, for example start() and join() in _threading_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: ignore the [`thread`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/thread.html) module and just use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html).

The `thread` and `threading` module serve quite different purposes. The `thread` module is a low-level module written in C, designed to abstract away platform differences and provide a *minimal* cross-platform set of primitives (essentially, threads and simple locks) that can serve as a foundation for higher-level APIs. If you were porting Python to a new platform that didn't support existing threading APIs (like POSIX threads, for example), then you'd have to edit the `thread` module source so that you could wrap the appropriate OS-level calls to provide those same primitives on your new platform.

As an example, if you look at the current CPython implementation, you'll see that a Python `Lock` is based on unnamed POSIX semaphores on Linux, on a combination of a POSIX condition variable and a POSIX mutex on OS X (which doesn't support unnamed semaphores), and on an `Event` and a collection of Windows-specific library calls providing various atomic operations on Windows. As a Python user, you don't want to have to care about those details. The `thread` module provides the abstraction layer that lets you build higher-level code without worrying about platform-level details.

As such, the `thread` module is really there as a convenience for those developing Python, rather than for those using it: it's not something that normal Python users are expected to need to deal with. For that reason, the module has been renamed to [`_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/_thread.html#module-_thread) in Python 3: the leading underscore indicates that it's private, and that users shouldn't rely on its API or behaviour going forward.

In contrast, the `threading`-module is a Java-inspired module written in Python. It builds on the foundations laid by the `thread` module to provide a convenient API for starting and joining threads, and a broad set of concurrency primitives (re-entrant locks, events, condition variables, semaphores, barriers and so on) for users. This is almost always the module that you as a Python user want to be using. If you're interested in what's going on behind the scenes, it's worth taking some time to look at the [`threading` source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/threading.py): you can see how the `threading` module pulls in the primitives it needs from the `thread` module and puts everything together to provide that higher-level API.

Note that there are different tradeoffs here, from the perspective of the Python core developers. On the one hand, it should be easy to port Python to a new platform, so the `thread` module should be small: you should only have to implement a few basic primitives to get up and running on your new platform. In contrast, Python *users* want a wide variety of concurrency primitives, so the `threading` library needs to be extensive to support the needs of those users. Splitting the threading functionality into two separate layers is a good way of providing what the users need while not making it unnecessarily hard to maintain Python on a variety of platforms.

To answer your specific question: if you *must* use the `thread` library directly (despite all I've said above), you can do this:

```
import thread
import time

def main():
    t1=thread.start_new_thread(prints,(3,))
    t2=thread.start_new_thread(prints,(5,))

def prints(i):
    while(i>0):
        print "i="+str(i)+"\n"
        i=i-1

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
    # Give time for the output to show up.
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

But of course, using a `time.sleep` is a pretty shoddy way of handling things in the main thread: really, we want to wait until both child threads have done their job before exiting. So we'd need to build some functionality where the main thread can wait for child threads. That functionality doesn't exist directly in the `thread` module, but it does in `threading`: that's exactly the point of the `threading` module: it provides a rich, easy-to-use API in place of the minimal, hard-to-use `thread` API. So we're back to the summary line: don't use `thread`, use `threading`.